# Exception when run Aspnet Mvc app on OS X

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, kvm, asp.net-core, kruntime

I'm trying to run samples for aspnet 5 on os x:
git clone https://github.com/shirhatti/Home.git

When I build the project HelloMvc -- 'kpm build' -- it's ok.
Then I run app using 'k kestrel' and see the following error:

> Missing method Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation::get_LoadableAssemblies() in assembly data-0x7feb6aa02a00, referenced in assembly /Users/minya/.kpm/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/6.0.0-beta2-11905/lib/aspnet50/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.dll
>       System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation.get_LoadableAssemblies'.
>         at System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator12`2[Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation,System.Reflection.AssemblyName].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator10`2[System.Reflection.AssemblyName,System.Reflection.Assembly].MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator12`2[System.Reflection.Assembly,System.Reflection.TypeInfo].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.Invoke (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionDescriptorProviderContext context, System.Action callNext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.NestedProviders.NestedProviderManager`1+CallNext[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionDescriptorProviderContext].CallNextProvider () [0x00000] in :0 
>         at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.NestedProviders.NestedProviderManager`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionDescriptorProviderContext].Invoke (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionDescriptorProviderContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.GetCollection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRouting.GetActionDescriptors (IServiceProvider services) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute (IRouter target, IServiceProvider services) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc (IApplicationBuilder app, System.Action`1 configureRoutes) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc (IApplicationBuilder app) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at KWebStartup.Startup.Configure (IApplicationBuilder app) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>         at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0

There is no exact problem in google. I was tried to reinstall kvm, delete and checkout NuGet deps.

Updated:
Similar behavior on Windows when I try to run the same project by 'k web':

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Reflection.AssemblyName> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryInformation.g
>   et_LoadableAssemblies()'.
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultAssemblyProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0.<get_CandidateAssemblies>b__1(ILibraryInformation l)
>
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.Invoke(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context, Action callNext)
>
>      at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.NestedProviders.NestedProviderManager`1.CallNext.CallNextProvider()
>      at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.NestedProviders.NestedProviderManager`1.Invoke(T context)
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.GetCollection()
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRouting.GetActionDescriptors(IServiceProvider services)
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(IRouter target, IServiceProvider services)
>
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 configureRoutes)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at HelloMvc.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) in C:\prj\Home\samples\HelloMvc\Startup.cs:line 18

Seems to be the problem is in one (or more) of referenced in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.* assemblies. This is disassemble of DefaultAssemblyProvider from Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core. I guess the problem is in ILibraryManager's implementations GetReferencingLibraries() method. But I can't find this implementation.

```
public class DefaultAssemblyProvider : IAssemblyProvider
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> _mvcAssemblyList;
    private readonly ILibraryManager _libraryManager;

    public IEnumerable<Assembly> CandidateAssemblies
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Select<AssemblyName, Assembly>(Enumerable.SelectMany<ILibraryInformation, AssemblyName>(this.GetCandidateLibraries(), DefaultAssemblyProvider.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 ?? (DefaultAssemblyProvider.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 = new Func<ILibraryInformation, IEnumerable<AssemblyName>>(DefaultAssemblyProvider.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0.CS\u0024\u003C\u003E9__inst.\u003Cget_CandidateAssemblies\u003Eb__1))), new Func<AssemblyName, Assembly>(DefaultAssemblyProvider.Load));
        }
    }

    static DefaultAssemblyProvider()
    {
        HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>((IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.Ordinal);
        string str1 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc";
        hashSet.Add(str1);
        string str2 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core";
        hashSet.Add(str2);
        string str3 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding";
        hashSet.Add(str3);
        string str4 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor";
        hashSet.Add(str4);
        string str5 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host";
        hashSet.Add(str5);
        string str6 = "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering";
        hashSet.Add(str6);
        DefaultAssemblyProvider._mvcAssemblyList = hashSet;
    }

    public DefaultAssemblyProvider(ILibraryManager libraryManager)
    {
        this._libraryManager = libraryManager;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<ILibraryInformation> GetCandidateLibraries()
    {
        return Enumerable.Where<ILibraryInformation>(Enumerable.Distinct<ILibraryInformation>(Enumerable.SelectMany<string, ILibraryInformation>((IEnumerable<string>) DefaultAssemblyProvider._mvcAssemblyList, new Func<string, IEnumerable<ILibraryInformation>>(this._libraryManager.GetReferencingLibraries))), new Func<ILibraryInformation, bool>(DefaultAssemblyProvider.IsCandidateLibrary));
    }

    private static Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    }

    private static bool IsCandidateLibrary(ILibraryInformation library)
    {
        return !DefaultAssemblyProvider._mvcAssemblyList.Contains(library.get_Name());
    }
}
```

Comment: several things: 
1). No where in here is a question.
2). Please format your error snippet.
3). Please show us what you've done to try to solve your problem before tossing it out in here. We are not your personal GoG (Group of Googlers)

Comment: @JSKNS Thanks for comments. Sorry for first version.

Comment: What's the output of `kvm list`?

Comment: `Active Version              Runtime Architecture Location
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------
       1.0.0-beta1          Mono.1.0.0 x86          /Users/minya/.kre/packages
`       1.0.0-alpha3-10143   mono45  x86          /Users/minya/.kre/packages
  *    1.0.0-alpha4-10353   mono45  x86          /Users/minya/.kre/packages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Windows and found the wrong KRE was active.

Executing `kvm list` shows a list of KRE. In my case the `1.0.0-alpha4` version was active instead of the more recent beta version.

Switching to the default with `kvm use default` sorted it out for me.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. I detected that I have 2 different KRE's on my machine. First in my home (~/.kre/) and second in /usr/local/Cellar/kre. Then In addition I was unable to choose beta1 of kre using kvm use. So I deleted all of kre, kvm, kpm packages from my machine and installed again. And now all works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by updating my version of KVM, there is probably a simpler way but, assuming you initially installed using homebrew, running these commands should solve your issue

- brew untap aspnet/k
- brew tap aspnet/k
- brew install kvm

then you should be able to run k kestrel

if you get a message that kvm is already installed then:

- brew link --overwrite mono
- brew uninstall mono
- brew reinstall kvm

Comment: updated answer with more info if brew says kvm installed

Comment: I've tried to run same app in windows. And I've got similar error. I had updated my post. I think there is no problems in kre. Instead, seems to be the problem is in asp.net libraries.

Comment: Yeah I think with hindsight the reinstall of kvm just updated some mono dependencies in the background and this sorted out the issue for me

Comment: What version of mono are you running?

Comment: kre version is  1.0.0-alpha4-10353   mono45  x86; mono --version: Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 (tarball Wed Oct 22 10:06:03 BST 2014)